# how to migrate AWS old generation instance to current generation instance without losing data

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to migrate my old geneartion instance to new geneartion instance from paravirtual to hvm machines, I detached pm machine's old root volume and detached the new hvm root volume. I attached pm root volume to hvm machine as  **/dev/sda1**, and started the server. It started and stopped after seconds. I dont know whats happening, have some one had the same problem? Also How to migrate without creating problem in processes which my old pm server had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing paravirtual machine's root will not work with hvm type machine. One thing can do is [Use this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=648055), the working script is at the bottom of the script. That is used to convert para virtual to hvm. But note this will take extraoridinary downtime. Face it.  But it works. Or, Create a new instance and install the softwares from scratch taking the logs, files you need as a backup. And attach the volumes to the new instance. Volumes can be attached without any problem unless they are in the same region. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a new ebs volume to old machine, then mount your data to this volume. 
Take snapshot from this volume and start a new instance then attach snapshot to it.

Comment: Actually changing the virtualization type from paravirtual to hvm is not happening. I detached the root volume, made a new instance, attached that to the new instance, it starts and shutdowns in a minute.

Comment: You need to mount your data only not the fs to the new volume, then reserve it as a snapshot, launch new instance with it's own AMI say AMZ Linux 2 then attach your snapshot and mount it.